# How do I View Specification Name?

Tags: ms-access

I am reviewing an Access database of a coworker who left a macro in the database, but I want to understand what the macro does exactly. In design view, I open the macro and see there is a Specification Name field that seems to have everything I want. How do I view that file??

Comment: There really isn't enough information in your question to begin to answer it. You have to give more details on what the macro does, by indicating the macro command and the arguments defined for it. Maybe if you did a SaveAsText you could post the result: Application.SaveAsText acMacro,"MyMacro","MyMacro.txt".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifications are stored in System tables (MSysIMEXSpecs, MSysIMEXColumns) but it is probably easier to choose to import manually, choose Advanced and then choose Specs.